# Docker cannot establish connection with postgresql in Travis CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, travis-ci

I'm trying to integrate Travis CI into my rails app. Everything works fine on my local machine(ubuntu, windows), but on travis host there is a connection error. So, here are my configurations.

`.travis.yml`:

```
sudo: required

language: ruby

services:
  - docker

env:
  DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION: 1.13.0

before_install:
  - sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > docker-compose
  - chmod +x docker-compose
  - sudo mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" install docker-engine
  - docker-compose build
  - docker-compose -f docker-compose.commands.yml run --rm website rails db:create db:migrate db:test:prepare

script:
 - docker-compose -f docker-compose.commands.yml run --rm -e RAILS_ENV=test website rspec
```

`database.yml`:

```
development: &default
adapter: postgresql
database: my_app_development
username: postgres
host: postgres
port: 5432
```

`docker-compose.commands.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.6.2'
    ports:
      - "5432"

  website:
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000'
  volumes:
    - '.:/my_app'
    - 'bundle_data:/bundle'

 volumes:
  bundle_data:
```

But travis log outputs this when it runs migrations

> Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:9.6.2
>
> Creating myapp_postgres_1 ...
>
> Creating myapp_postgres_1
>
> could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "postgres" (172.18.0.2) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>   Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"my_app_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"postgres", "host"=>"postgres", "port"=>5432}
>   rails aborted!
>   PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "postgres" (172.18.0.2) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Likely a timing issue. `depends_on` does not wait for postgres to be ready, just for the container to start. Look at using something like `wait-for-it.sh` to wait for postgres to be up before connecting to it.

Comment: I don't think so, please see updated log output description

Comment: I don't see anything in the extra log that changes my opinion?

Comment: the error occures after database container was created. Doesn't that mean that database is ready?

Comment: No, like I said, container created != postgres ready to accept connections.

Comment: like @johnharris85 is saying, a database must initialize when it starts for the first time (and on subsequent starts) and this process can take several or even dozens of seconds. The docker library MySQL container takes 10 seconds sometimes before it starts. You might need to map the postgres container port to the host so you can check if postgres is running and ready for connections. Then you could use wait-for-it or just something like: until nc -z -v -w30 127.0.0.1 5432; do sleep 2; done

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @johnharris85 and @jbielick I've found this solution:

```
website:
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/my_app'
      - 'bundle_data:/bundle'
    entrypoint: ./wait-for-postgres.sh postgres 5432

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.6.2'
    ports:
      - '5432'
```

`wait-for-postgres.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

postgres_host=$1
postgres_port=$2
shift 2
cmd="$@"

# wait for the postgres docker to be running
while ! pg_isready -h $postgres_host -p $postgres_port -q -U postgres; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"

# run the command
exec $cmd
```